# How to get the value associated with min of one column and the value associated with the max of the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an original table with records of orders. How can go about getting an output where my result gives me the origin of the first leg and the destination of the final leg for the same order number?

| ORDER_NUMBER | LEG_NUMBER | ORIGIN | DESTINATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORD_200 | 1 | Utah | California |
| ORD_200 | 2 | California | New York |
| ORD_200 | 3 | New York | Pennsylvania |

Desired Output:

| ORDER_NUMBER | ORIGIN | DESTINATION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ORD_200 | Utah | Pennsylvania |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function and `distinct`

```
select distinct ORDER_NUMBER
      , first_value(ORIGIN) over(partition by ORDER_NUMBER order by LEG_NUMBER ) ORIGIN
      , first_value(DESTINATION) over(partition by ORDER_NUMBER order by LEG_NUMBER desc) DESTINATION
from tbl
```

Comment: `last_value` with `asc`  on `DESTINATION` would be slightly more efficient